# Shift in origin for polar coordinates

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems

Consider a set of polar coordinates, $(r, \theta)$ for a plane. Let's say there is a point, at $\left(1,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ for which I want to define a translated and rotated coordinate system, $(R, \Theta)$ for which that point has the coordinates $(0,0)$.

I just want to verify here, the transformation is given by $R = r - 1$ and $\Theta = \theta - \frac{\pi}{4}$, correct?

Comment: Your transformation appears to be correct.

Comment: When $r<1$ your proposed formula gives $R<0,$ so your coordinates $(R,\Theta)$ are certainly not polar coordinates about the new point, if that is what you were intending.

Comment: Are $\bigl(1,{\pi\over4}\bigr)$ and $(0,0)$ meant to be old and new cartesian coordinates of the same point? $(0,0)$ doesn't make sense as pair of polar coordinate values.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Suppose we want to define new coordinates $(R, \Theta)$ using a reference point $(\rho, \alpha)$ given in the original polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$. Then, the old polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ and new polar coordinates $(R, \Theta)$ of the arbitrary (red) point are related as in the diagram below.

By the Law of Cosines, $$R^2 = r^2 + \rho^2 - 2 \rho r \cos (\theta - \alpha) .$$

Likewise, the Law of Sines gives
$$\sin \Theta = \frac{r}{R} \sin (\theta - \alpha) .$$

[image]

Comment: how do I get r, theta in terms of R,phi?

Comment: By symmetry, we can see that it's the same procedure, except that the new reference point (i.e., the origin of the $(r, \theta)$ coordinate system) in the new $(R, \Theta)$ coordinates is $(-\rho, -\alpha)$. In particular, if you can solve for $(R, \Theta)$ in terms of $(r, \theta)$, you can do the reverse just as easily.

Answer (score 0):

> Hint

We can consider polar coordinates as vectors and then use vector subtraction
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. $rsin\theta=\rho.sin\alpha+Rcos(\phi-(\frac\pi2-\alpha))$

---

[image]

2. $rsin(\theta-\alpha)=Rsin(\pi-\phi)$

   - $rsin\theta.cos\alpha-rcos\theta.sin\alpha=Rsin\phi$
   - $[\rho.sin\alpha+Rcos(\phi-(\frac\pi2-\alpha))]cos\alpha-rcos\theta.sin\alpha=Rsin\phi$
   - $rcos\theta=\frac{[\rho.sin\alpha+Rcos(\phi-(\frac\pi2-\alpha))]cos\alpha-Rsin\phi}{sin\alpha}$

$r=\sqrt((rcos\theta)^2+(rsin\theta)^2)$

$tan\theta=\frac{rsin\theta}{rcos\theta}$

Substitute r, $\theta$ wherever you need